# Java control panel in Windows 10

Tags: windows

All of the answers concerning Java Control Panel in Windows 10 keep saying to access the Control Panel - well, news flash, there is NO control panel.  Everything has been moved to Settings in Windows 10 so how do I find Java Control Panel in Windows 10 for real?

Comment: There is still a control panel in Windows 10 (search start for **Control Panel** or Run **control.exe**)

Comment: @YisroelTech, OP is asking about "Java Control Panel" it is different from Windows OS Control Panel.

Comment: @Dush read again... He says everyone sends him to "the control panel" (from windows) where he will find the Java control panel, but he thinks that Windows 10 doesn't have a control panel

Comment: @YisroelTech, Yes, you were right since your are not answering the question, but you were just commenting about his belief that Windows control panel is not there any more. I just miss understood your comment since I was thinking about OPs final question.

Comment: Java control panel has also disappeared from my windows control panel, the questioner isn't delusional.

Answer (score 3):

Alternate method of launching Java Control Panel:

Click Windows Start button.
In the Start Search box, type:

- Windows 32-bit OS:

  ```
  C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javacpl.exe**
  ```
- Windows 64-bit OS:

  ```
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javacpl.exe**
  ```

Ref: [Docs](https://java.com/en/download/help/win_controlpanel.xml#:%7E:text=Versions%20below%207u40-,Windows%2010,open%20the%20Java%20Control%20Panel.)

Comment: Note that the "jre7" part of the path will change as new versions are released, so navigate to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\" and see what's there.

Answer (score 1):

If you really don't have shortcut to "**Configure Java**" in the menu start, then run directly this Java Panel by accessing **C:\Program Files\Java\jreJAVA_VERSION\bin\javacpl.exe** or **C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jreJAVA_VERSION\bin\javacpl.exe**

If you only have jdk installed, then **C:\Program Files\Java\jdkJAVA_VERSION\jre\bin\javacpl.exe**

Answer (score 0):

We can try the following three ways to find java control panel:

Right click the Start button and choose "**Control Panel**".
In the "**Search Control Panel**" box, type "Java".
It should bring up a match entitled "Java (XX-bit)" (where XX is the bit-level of the Java install)
Double-click that icon to open the Java Control Panel.

We can see the versions of Java installed on our PC by opening the "**Programs and Features**" control panel.
We can get there by right click on the Start button to open "**Control Panel**" and then open "**Program and Features**".

To locate the Java Control panel, type **Configure Java** in the search bar on the side. 
Here are two links to downloading the Java JRE if we need to download it again.

https://java.com/en/download/

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10, you can NOT easily find the Java Control Panel.

For this:
1: open a command prompt
2: type: control.exe
3: choose Programs
4: Click Java
and there you are.

Answer (score 0):

Guys: OpenJDK doesn't have a java control panel. Best bet is to install an older version of th OpenJDK which still has the control panel.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).